# Excel Map Chart doesn't display region propertly

Tags: excel, office365, visualization, bing-maps

Apparently Bing doesn't recognize two regions of Costa Rica. I've tried using ISO 3166-2 and other standars but the problem is persists.

Regions without ploting: Puntarenas and Limon.

Is there another standard that I have to use?

Thanks guys

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bing data is often not very good with data for regions outside of the US. I have the same problem with New Zealand data. The only thing you can do is give feedback and report the problem. In my version of Excel (365, Insider), I can click File > Feedback and send a frown. I know that Microsoft keep a tight watch on that feedback channel.

Comment: Thanks for your reply :D, I've spent 3 hours triying to achieve this. The feedback has already sent.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be issue with Excel implementation as Bing Maps have data for those regions.
[Costa Rica Provinces with Bing Maps Geodata API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRcd4.jpg)

You can check this on Bing Maps v8 iSDK: https://www.bing.com/api/maps/sdkrelease/mapcontrol/isdk/sdsloadboundaryfromsearch#overview
Just change *New York City* to *Puntarenas* or *Limon* on line 6 of code window, and on line 11 *PopulatedPlace* to *AdminDivision1* then click on run button.